# Unwanted new line between paragraphs

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs

I have a .tex file in which I defined the below code:

```
\section{Introduction}
\paragraph{}
This is an example
\paragraph{}
This is an example
```

which is shown like this:

[image]

How can I avoid to have the empty new line between the two paragraphs? My main.tex is defined as this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage{indentfirst}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{logo uniba.png}
    \label{fig:enter-label}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
    Università degli Studi di Bari "Aldo Moro"

    
    Master's Degree in Computer Science
\end{center}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\begin{center}
    Thesis in Artificial Intelligence for Security
\end{center}
\vspace{15mm}
\begin{center}
    \large \textbf{A study based on XAI of the performance of a feature-based classifier learned  for PE malware classification and evaluated on adversarial samples generated in the problem space}
\end{center}

\vfill

\raggedright\textbf{\textbf{First supervisor:}}

Annalisa Appice

\textbf{\textbf{Second supervisor:}}
\hfill
\textbf{\textbf{Graduating student:}}

Giuseppina Andresini
\hfill
Paolo Gasparro

\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}

\begin{center}
    Academic year 2022-2023
\end{center}

\newpage

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Index}

\begin{center}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
\end{center}

\input{Chapters/Introduction}
\input{Chapters/Background}
\input{Chapters/Defined Pipeline}
\input{Chapters/Experimental Study}
\input{Chapters/Conclusions and future works}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: \paragraph` is a 4th level section head after section, subsection, subsection, paragraph, subparagraph.  It shoul dnot be used after `\section` or with an empty argument (which is the section title)

Comment: the `\raggedright` in `\raggedright\textbf{\textbf{First supervisor:}}` applies to the entire document, was that intended?

Comment: Just replace `\paragraph{}` by a blank line which is the standard markup for paragraphs of text in latex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle if I remove ```\paragraph{}``` I don't have more the indentation. How to indent the first line?

Comment: The first paragraph of a section is not indented by default. If you want to change that use the `indentfirst` package (that I wrote::-) which you have but have commented out.

Comment: You do not get paragraph indentation from `\paragraph{]` you do get some weird extra white space from the empty section head but it will not match the paragraph identation in normal paragraphs.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I uncommented ```indentfirst``` package but the first line of the section still stays not indented. How is that possible?

Comment: because as I said above you have specified the entire document is `\raggedright` so no paragraph indentation and no text justifcation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was intended to use ```\raggedright``` and ```\raggedleft``` just to specify the first and second supervisor and the graduating student. How can I limit this commands not to the entire document but just to the first page?

Comment: use `\begin{flushleft}...\end{flushleft}`  (or flushright, depending which way you want to go)

Answer (score 1):

You provided no example code to show the problem, but it seems you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}

\section{Aaaa Bbbb}

An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 

An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 


\end{document}
```

The main error was use of `\raggedright` which sets paragraph indent to 0 and disables justification of the right margin:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\begin{document}
\raggedright

\section{Aaaa Bbbb}

An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 

An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 
An indented paragraph. An indented paragraph. 


\end{document}
```

---

Despite its unfortunate name, `\paragraph` is unrelated to textual paragraphs (which should be marked by a blank line in the source) it is the 4th level heading after `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection` so should only be used after `\subsubsection` (and should not be used with empty argument as the numbering and table of contents will look very odd if you increase `secnumdepth`).